# How to print tab(\t) inside a div element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need tabulation without using space (`&nbsp;`) and without text-indent.

I need to copy a text in div element with tab.

How to do it without textarea?

Comment: why do you want it? What did you try for it??

Comment: @Jai I tried to use a tab \t symbol inside div element and it doesn't work. I have no more ideas. Sorry.

Comment: @owl Why do you want to use \t in a div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to print tab you can use `&emsp;`

```
document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML = "&emsp;"+"tab printed";
```